# starting and stopping css3 animation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Im making an animation with css3 for firefox at the moment.

```
$("#slide5").click(function(){
     $("#move").css("-moz-animation-play-state", "running");            
});
```

I already found out that the code above will make my animation start.
But, now I was wondering. Is there a way to make it start with this code and with another click pause it again?

Hope you guys can help me.
Cheers in advance!

Comment: Easiest way might be to add and remove classes instead of styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#slide5" ).toggle(function() {
    $("#move").css("-moz-animation-play-state", "running");  
}, function() {
    $("#move").css("-moz-animation-play-state", "paused");  
});
```

this works on all 'modern' browsers

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
$("#move").css("-moz-animation-play-state", "paused");
```

If that didn't work, with this:

```
$("#move").css("-moz-animation-play-state", "");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers